# CRM 2011 GUID ID

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, guid

I'm pulling information from CRM to generate a soap message to be sent to a server. The problem is that CRM uses GUIDs for id and the Xsd for the SOAP server requires a int.

Is there a table that tracks all entity creations and their associated GUID Id? My thinking is that I can simply create  a trigger on this table and map the GUID to a Int in a lookup table so that I can replace the GUID with a int ID. Any other suggestions are welcome

Comment: can you explain this? "and the Xsd for the SOAP server requires a int."
It is an external system?

Comment: I actually came up with a solution, I'm just storing the GUID and a new id in a lookup table, but Im still interested to know if there is a table in CRM that tracks entity creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no master table of all records created in Dynamics CRM. You would have to look at each entity's SQL table individually.